# JavaScript nested Array with nested maps

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a nested array

```
const array = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
```

I want to return a single array like `[2,4,6,8]`.
I did this:

```
const result = array.map((x)=>{
  return x.map((y)=>y*2)
  });
```

But it returned `[[2,4],[6,8]]`.
What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: Use `array.flatMap(x => x.map(y => y*2))` or `array.map(x => x.map(y => y*2)).flat()`

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
];
const result = array.reduce((elem, accum) => accum.concat([...elem]), []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You could even eliminate the concat call by using the spread operator: `(elem, accum) => [...accum, ...elem])`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert 2D array to 1D array use

```
result = [].concat(...result);
```

```js
const array = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];


var result = array.map((x)=>{
  return x.map((y)=>y*2)
  });
  
result = [].concat(...result);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
array.flat(Infinity)

// [1, [2, [3]]].flat(Infinity) =>  [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply looking for `Array.prototype.flatMap` -

```js
const array =
  [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

const result =
  array.flatMap(a => a.map(x => x * 2))
  
console.log(result)
// [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```